# How to listen for Picasso (Android) load complete events?

Tags: java, android, picasso

Is there a way to listen for events from Picasso when using the builder like:

`Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);`

I'm trying to call `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` on the parent `GridView` so it'll resize properly but I don't know how to set a listener or callback.

I see that Picasso has error event reporting, but is there a success event?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

You can use a `Callback` to get onSuccess and onError events. Just add a new Callback to your request like so:

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
```

Then you can perform any alterations and modifications in the onSuccess callback.

Comment: How to show error image when onError() is executed??

Comment: Use `.error(R.drawable.error_placeholder_image)` to set error image

Comment: How can I access the 'this' context from inside onSuccess? I need to update some variables in the 'this' context, and also how can I access the imageView inside the callback? Thx

Comment: Try this YourClassName.this.yourVariable @sonoluminescence

Answer (score 32):

If you need to access the bitmap before it is loaded to the view, try using :

```
private Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {       
      }
      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed() {
      }
}
```

In the calling method:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
```

Ideally you'd implement Target on a view or view holder object directly.

Hope this helps

Comment: where is the imgView?

Comment: @NoorHossain set image bitmap when bitmap loaded

Answer (score 9):

Answering @Jas follow up question as a comment to MrEngineer13's answer (since I don't have enough reputation to comment in any answer), you should use the `error()` method prior to registering the `Callback` at the `into()` method, for example:

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(url)
    .error(R.drawable.error_placeholder_image)
    .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            //Success image already loaded into the view
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            //Error placeholder image already loaded into the view, do further handling of this situation here
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Square lately has updated Target class and now there are more methods to override (`onPrepareLoad` and `onBitmapFailed`):

```
Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
};
```

And you still have to use:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(target);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 private final Callback mImageCallback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            startPostponedEnterTransition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            startPostponedEnterTransition();
        }
    };

RequestCreator creator = Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(list.get(position).getId());
creator.into(imageView, mImageCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
       Picasso.with(context)
            .load(services.get(position).getImageInactive())
            .into(holder.icon, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    holder.imageLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_error_image_load);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to other answers, in case you don't know where to use original image view, e.g. `ImageView myIV`:

Original:

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(url).into(myIV);
```

New (inside `onBitmapLoaded()` of `new Target()`):

```
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    myIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```