# How to know Image downloaded by picasso or not?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using `picasso` in my application, but I'm facing one problem with that.
I showing users profile images in `Listview` and if image is not present I want to show user's name initials at `ImageView`. I able to show profile image if present but for showing initials how I come to know that user don't have image.?

Comment: You should handle with your model data. If(user.getImageUrl()!=null){//loadImageWithPicasso}else{//do what you want}. Or passing to picasso wrong url, and handle result passing callback to Picasso.load() overriding OnError.

Comment: I'm preparing URL runtime so I don't know image available for user or not

Comment: Then you should pass Callback to handle onError, when url not exist or another error.

Comment: Something like this `Picasso.load(url).into(imageview, new Callback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
              
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                 //create ImageView with initials and pass to imageview
            }
        });
`

Comment: @encastellano write it as an answer

Comment: Something like this `Picasso.load(url).into(imageview, new Callback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
              
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                 //create ImageView with initials and pass to imageview
            }
        });
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548660/how-to-listen-for-picasso-android-load-complete-events

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `placeholder()` and `error()` method to load the default which you want to bind.

`placeholder()`, will be visible  until the image is loaded.
`error()`, will be visible when the error occurs during the loading from the url

```
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
```