# Picasso image load is showing blank

Tags: android, image, picasso

I want to load an image from server into the `ImageView`. But I'm unable to load it but when i'm trying to load other images of the tutorial it work fine.

Here is my [image url](http://gpsapp.ultimatefreehost.in/main.jpeg) (Failed to load) [image url](http://www.empireonline.com/images/uploaded/wreck-it-ralph-box-office.jpg) (which can be load).

I cant understand that why this problem arise either it's size or dimension.

Please guide me.

Comment: Can you post the logcat? Showing which images DO load doesn't help too much.

Comment: you are uploading your image? the image you are uploading is not working ?but other image is displaying

Comment: yes the image is not working but the image from other tutorials are working in my code and it is easily loading it there

Comment: try using callback , is your url is doing success or error ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548894/1602333